# for ... in loop with string array outputs indices

Tags: javascript

When I write some javascript such as this:

```
var words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']

for (word in words) {
    console.log(word)
}
```

The resulting output is the numeric indices of the respective word.  I did some searching on Google and I couldn't find the exact reason for this behavior.  I'm guessing that this is completely expected behavior but I would like to know the reason why.

Thanks!

Comment: See [Why is using `for…in` on arrays such a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)

Comment: In ES6 you can use: `for (word of words) { console.log(word); }`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Why is nobody providing the correct answer?  You NEVER iterate arrays with a `for/in` loop - that is only for iterating plain objects and their keys, not for iterating the items in an array.

You iterate arrays for a for loop like this:

```
var words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3'];

for (var i = 0, len = words.length; i < len; i++) {
    // here words[i] is the array element
}
```

Or you can use the `.forEach()` method of arrays:

```
var words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3'];

words.forEach(function(value, index, array) {
    // here value is the array element being iterated
});
```

See [here at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for more info on `.forEach()`.

ndp's reference to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays/500531#500531) shows some good examples of things that can go wrong using `for/in` with arrays.  You can make it works sometimes, but it is not the smart way to write Javascript array iteration.

---

**Or, in more modern times,** you can use the ES6 `for/of` construct which is specially built for iterating an iterable (an array is an iterable):

```
var words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3'];

for (const w of words) {
    console.log(w);
}
```

Or, if you want both the value and the index, you can do this:

```
var words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3'];

for (const [index, w] of words.entries()) {
    console.log(index, ": ", w);
}
```

There are several advantages of `for/of` over `.forEach()`.  To start with, you have more loop control as you can use `break`, `continue`, `return` to control the loop flow which `.forEach()` does not give you.  In addition, there's no additional overhead for a callback function so, in some environments, it can be faster.

Comment: Added ES6 options.

Answer (score 1):

1. for..in is used to iterate over the properties of a javascript object.
2. Think of an array as a javascript object with indexes as properties.

Answer (score 1):

`For ... in` is intended for [objects](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for_in.asp) -- see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays). Apparently it can (and is) used for arrays, but this has a few risks you may not want.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers correctly point out, `for...in` is not for iterating over arrays. A better option is now available in newer JavaScript engines and transpilers like TypeScript with [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of):

```
var words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']

for (word of words) {
    console.log(word)
}
```