# Javascript loop an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a javascript array written like this...

```
var json = [
    {"id":"1", "title":"Test 1", "comment":"This is the first test"},
    {"id":"2", "title":"Test 2", "comment":"This is the second test"}
];
```

what I am trying to do is get each one of the ids.

I have been trying this

```
for(x in json[0]){
    alert(x.id);        
}
```

But no luck, can someone point me in the right direction? Please and thank you :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [for ... in loop with string array outputs indices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480020/for-in-loop-with-string-array-outputs-indices)

Comment: You probably find it helpful as well to read the [`for...in` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x` in your example is giving you the **indexes** of you array, not the objects.  You could do:

```
for(x in json) {
    alert(json[x].id);        
}
```

but to loop through an array you're really better off with a "regular" for loop

```
for (var i = 0, max = json.length; i < max; i++) {
    alert(json[i].id);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Any modern browser will allow you to do it easily:

```
var ids = json.map(function(i) { return i.id; });
// and now you have an array of ids!
```

Sadly, "modern" does not include IE 8 and earlier.

You can also do the "mundane" form, which is guaranteed to work in all browsers. I see Adam Rackis has beat me to it though, so I 'll go upvote his answer and you should probably do so as well.

Comment: +1 - nice - I really need to start using these ES5 methods more.  And `Sadly, "modern" does not include IE 8` ftw

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible solution:

```
var json = [{"id":"1","title":"Test 1","comment":"This is the first test"},{"id":"2","title":"Test 2","comment":"This is the second test"}];

for (var i = 0, len = json.length; i < len; i++) {
    alert(json[i].id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `for(x in y)` loop in JavaScript gives you the indexes in that array (e.g., so that `x[y]` gives you the current element).

The two proper ways to loop through an array in JavaScript are:

```
for(x = 0; x < y.length; x++) { // (this can only loop through arrays)
  // do something with y[x]
}
for(x in y) { // (this can loop through objects too)
  // do something with y[x]
}
```