# Use for loop to print values in an array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning JavaScript and now I am trying to run the following codes in Node to display the values in an array:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3];
for (let a in array) {
    console.log(a);
}
```

I expect the above codes will print 1, 2 and 3

However, it prints 0, 1, 2.

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong in my code?

Comment: `console.log(array[a])`. `a` is the increment. I don't recommend using a for in loop on an Array though. Use `array.forEach(function(value, increment){})`, or just a regular `for` loop if you want to break out of it, for faster execution. In the `forEach` loop `value` will have your value without needing array[increment].

Comment: I can get the correct output now. So a is actually the index of the array.

Comment: Replace the `in` with `of`. `in` is for iterating over keys of an object, `of` is for iterating over values of an interable.

Comment: This is a very good question for beginners to learn the answer to, good job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use `for/in` for iterating an array.  And, when you were doing so, you were just getting the array indices, not the actual array elements.

`for/in` iterates all enumerable properties of the object, not just array elements which can end up including things you do not want.  See [for ... in loop with string array outputs indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480020/for-in-loop-with-string-array-outputs-indices/7480175#7480175) and [For loop for HTMLCollection elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754315/for-loop-for-htmlcollection-elements/22754453#22754453) for details.

Instead, you can use any number of other options.  The modern way is probably `for/of` which works for any iterable (which includes an array).

**for/of**

```
let array = [1, 2, 3];
for (let a of array) {
    console.log(a);
}
```

**.forEach()**

```
let array = [1, 2, 3];
array.forEach(function(a, index) {
    console.log(a);
});
```

**Plain for loop**

```
let array = [1, 2, 3];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: The `for..in` syntax grabs the `properties` of the object you iterate over, and not the `values` of the objects like you expect. The Mozilla Developer Network is a great resource and it is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...in_statement).

The properties of the array you are grabbing are the indices, to get the value you need to uses the property of the indices on the array using the array index operator `[]` like so.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3];
for (let a in array) {
    console.log(array[a]);
}
```

Or use the `for..of` syntax to get the value of the object like so.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3];
for (let a of array) {
    console.log(a);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let array = [1, 2, 3];
for (let a in array) {
    console.log(array[a]);
}
```

Comment: You should NEVER use `for/in` to iterate an array because that iterates all enumerable properties, not just array elements.  Use `for/of` or a `.forEach()` or  a regular `for` loop.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3];
for (let a in array) {
    console.log("index:  " + a + ', ' + "value:  " + array[a]);

}
```

Those are the array indices, starting at 0.  If you want the values, you need to get the value at that index.

Comment: You should NEVER use `for/in` to iterate an array because that iterates all enumerable properties, not just array elements.  Use `for/of` or a `.forEach()` or  a regular `for` loop.

Comment: Just curious about this `for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(array)) {
  console.log("index:  " + key + ": " + "value:  " + value);
}`. That can be used for objects and arrays ?  When would you use that ?

Comment: I don't think I would ever use that for an array because that will also include enumerable properties, not just array elements.  Works well for iterating the properties of an object, though.  If I wanted both index and item for an array, I'd either use `.forEach()` or `for (let [index, value] of array)` or a regular `for` loop.

Answer (score -2):

`a` is the increment, in your `for in` loop, so `array[a]` will give you the value in your case.

FYI...
Technically, it's a bad idea to use a `for in` loop on an Array, because `for in` loops receive properties as Strings, it's just that Arrays that receive Numeric Strings as values cast those values to Numbers.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3];
for(var i in array){
  console.log(typeof i);
}
```

I would do my Array loops like:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3];
array.forEach(function(val, inc){
  console.log(typeof inc);
  console.log(val);
});
// or
console.log('-------');
for(var i=0,l=array.length; i<l; i++){
  console.log(array[i]);
  if(i === 1)break;
}
// in a function
console.log('-------');
var anotherArray = array.concat([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);
function breakBefore(array, breakBefore, startAt){
  var i = startAt === undefined ? 0 : startAt;
  for(l=array.length; i<l; i++){
    console.log('increment:'+i);
    console.log('value:'+array[i]);
    if(i === breakBefore){
      return;
    }
  }
}
breakBefore(anotherArray, 6, 2);
```